# Partial success when Split With Lines on QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, splitting

I have two polygon feature and one multiline feature. I cut the polygon features using the line. Strangely, one of the polygons was successfully split (left one), but the other polygon failed.

[image]

Whats wrong? I am using QGIS 3.18. Files at [here](https://we.tl/t-coyBL35ykv)

Comment: How do you split your polygons, I mean which tool are you using?

Comment: I am using split with line tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The star marks a gap in your line, hence you can't cut the large polygon with it.

[image]

I found the gap when trying to recreate the line using the tracing option from the advanced digitizing toolbar.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful this answer is as the visualization does not provide a way to clearly identify the problematic spot and how to repair it. For the OP it would probably also be helpful to solve similar issues in the future if you provided an information how you found the problem.

Comment: I do agree about "how to" you've mentioned.

Comment: @Erik: great! Antother way to find the problematic spot is to create start- and end-point of the line with geometry generator with `start_point ($geometry)` and `end_point ($geometry)`: they are exactly where the gap is.

Comment: @panoet: if the answer was helpful, consider accepting the answer (hit the checkmark).

Comment: @Babel: off course I will. I just not tried it yet. A bit busy right now. Anyway, thank you in advance.